# Bootstrap coloring multiple words on one line?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, colors

I'm learning bootstrap currently (by the way it is AMAZING!) and i have a question. I have a 'h3' tag like so...

```
 <h3 class="pull-right">CALL 555-123-4567</h3>
```

what i'd like to do to style this tag is make the "call" part one color, and the phone number another color.

I know how to do it with css, but does bootstrap have anything to do with this? Do I need to make another class for the 'call' word seperate from the phone number?

For instance. . .

```
 <h3 class="pull-right"><h3 class="#">CALL</h3><h3 class="#">555-123-456</h3>
```

OR would it be more a ID like this?

```
 <div id="container"> <!--pull this right with bootstrap? would that even work? would the name need to be 'pull-right' and not container?-->
    <h3 class="colorChange"> CALL <h3> <h3 class="newColorChange" 555-123-4567</h3>
 </div>
```

Which is more proper? The original question of changing text color with bootstrap framework is my main concern.

Answer (score 2):

You should never nest **h3** inside a **h3** tag. To style **CALL** and **phone no.** separately, all you need to is this:

```
    <h3 class="pull-right">
     <span class="call">CALL</span>
     <span class="number">555-123-4567</span>
   </h3>
```

Now can style **CALL** and **Number** separately.

Comment: Thank you, i rarely use the span tag. This works perfectly.